# Editing existing key press event in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

This is a small piece of code for a project I'm working on for my study.

We have to make a program in Visual Basic (with Visual Studio 2015) that copies text from the first text box and pastes it into the second one once you press the button that states: "**Show Name**".

We are meant to handle it so that if the value entered is between 'A' to 'Z' then it copies the text and pastes it normally once you press the button into the second text box.

We are also supposed to make it so that, if the value is a number (between 0 and 9) we are meant to have a message which pops up saying something like: **"Error - You Entered a Number"**.

We are also supposed to make a box that pops up saying: **"Error - You Entered Something Other Than a Number"**, if the value is a character other than a letter or a number. I am in kind of a rush and would appreciate any help soon.

Here is my code so far. (I know `Keys.A` and `Keys.Z` and the message box is wrong, which I need to fix, too):

```
Public Class MyFirstProgram

Private Sub DisplayTextButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DisplayTextButton.Click
    ShowTextBox.Text = EnterTextBox.Text
End Sub
Private Sub me_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Dim letterEntered As Char
    If e.KeyCode < Keys.A Or e.KeyCode > Keys.Z Then
        MsgBox("Error - Use letter keys only!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, )
    Else
        letterEntered = LCase(ChrW(e.KeyCode))
        If ShowTextBox.Text = "" Then
            ShowTextBox.Text = letterEntered
        Else
            ShowTextBox.Text = ShowTextBox.Text + letterEntered
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClearButton.Click
    EnterTextBox.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub MyFirstProgram_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
 End Class
```

Oh, and I'm new to Visual Basic/programming; so, please try to be patient if you can. Sorry :/

Comment: Hi abadprogrammer, welcome to StackOverflow! While I understand you are in a rush to complete your assignment, I think it would be better for you to develop as a programmer if you tried it yourself and instead post specific questions on what the problem is, as opposed to broad requests to complete the assignment for you.

Comment: What do you mean by `char' here ..

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to implement this into my code

Comment: Consider not validating each keypress and scolding users for simple typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `KeyPress` press event .. instead of `keyDown`

```
Private Sub me_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    'If e.KeyCode < Keys.A Or e.KeyCode > Keys.Z Then
    '    MsgBox("Error - Use letter keys only!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, )
    'Else
    '    Dim letterEntered = LCase(ChrW(e.KeyCode))
    '    ShowTextBox.Text = ShowTextBox.Text + letterEntered

    'End If
    'e.Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
        MsgBox("Error - Use letter keys only!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just look in to the IsNumeric Function if it could help you.